# How do I get the width and height of a HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can i get the width and height of the canvas element in JavaScript?

Also, what is the "context" of the canvas I keep reading about?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

It might be worth looking at a tutorial: [MDN Canvas Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial)

You can get the width and height of a canvas element simply by accessing those properties of the element. For example:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
```

If the width and height attributes are not present in the canvas element, the default 300x150 size will be returned. To dynamically get the correct width and height use the following code:

```js
const canvasW = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width;
const canvasH = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

Or using the shorter object destructuring syntax:

```js
const { width, height } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
```

The `context` is an object you get from the canvas to allow you to draw into it. You can think of the `context` as the API to the canvas, that provides you with the commands that enable you to draw on the canvas element.

Comment: Note that the Mozilla tutorial is basically a bunch of broken links now, unfortunately. Hope they'll fix it some day.

Comment: This returns the context canvas size in Chrome 31.

Comment: this works only if `width` and `height` are specified directly as `<canvas />` tag attributes

Comment: That is not true. It always returns a value even without tag attributes, defaulting to 300 x 150.

Comment: Be aware that getBoundingClientRect() sometimes includes borders. This may or may not matter, but in my CSS I set the width and height to 100,100 and the getBoundingClientRect returns 102, 102. clientHeight and clientWidth (or scrollHeight and scrollWidth) return 100 correctly.

Comment: does not work with: canvas = document.getElementById( "myControl" ).getContext("2d");

Comment: @Z80 - Your `canvas` is a 2D context, not the canvas. `canvas` in the above is the HTML canvas element, not a 2D context.

Comment: Can someone (@andrewmu) explain why the `width` and `height` would not be available and need to return defaults? I'm getting these values (300,150) and yet the canvas is rendering full screen. When I draw my image on canvas, the image seems fully stretched. Do I need to wait for canvas element to be fully resized/rendered? Thanks.

Comment: @Jeach if you don't explicitly specify the width and height for the canvas element, you'll get the defaults. Those are logical pixel size values, meaning the image will have a resolution of width x height. It maybe be that your canvas has CSS properties that give it a different size, e.g. `width: 100%` or maybe it's in a flex container.  Then the canvas will display as a different size, but the image pixels in it will still be set by the width and height values (or the defaults) and scaled to fit the layout size.

Answer (score 41):

Well, all the answers before aren't entirely correct. 2 of major browsers don't support those 2 properties (IE is one of them) or use them differently.

Better solution (supported by most browsers, but I didn't check Safari):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var width = canvas.scrollWidth;
var height = canvas.scrollHeight;
```

At least I get correct values with scrollWidth and -Height and MUST set canvas.width and height when it is resized.

Comment: IE9 does seem to support canvas.width and height alright (versions prior to 9 did not support canvas at all), I've just given it a go. What troubles did you run into? And which is the other major browser?

Comment: Right, I really don't ever update IE because I don't use it. The other major browser is Opera which didn't / don't update width and height while resizing.

Comment: canvas.width or height dont return the total size of the canvas, prefer the canvas.scrollWidth or height to get the total real size of the canvas.

Comment: This worked for me, but the other answers didn't.  I was looking for a solution that could get the width and height if the canvas was set using bootstrap.

Answer (score 23):

The answers mentioning `canvas.width` return the internal dimensions of the canvas, i.e. those specified when creating the element:

```
<canvas width="500" height="200">
```

If you size the canvas with CSS, its DOM dimensions are accessible via `.scrollWidth` and `.scrollHeight`:

```js
var canvasElem = document.querySelector('canvas');
document.querySelector('#dom-dims').innerHTML = 'Canvas DOM element width x height: ' +
      canvasElem.scrollWidth +
      ' x ' +
      canvasElem.scrollHeight

var canvasContext = canvasElem.getContext('2d');
document.querySelector('#internal-dims').innerHTML = 'Canvas internal width x height: ' +
      canvasContext.canvas.width +
      ' x ' +
      canvasContext.canvas.height;

canvasContext.fillStyle = "#00A";
canvasContext.fillText("Distorted", 0, 10);
```

```html
<p id="dom-dims"></p>
<p id="internal-dims"></p>
<canvas style="width: 100%; height: 123px; border: 1px dashed black">
```

Comment: that was the correct answer.
2 dimensions to consider.

Comment: this should be the selected answer. direct `width` and `height` call will always return 300x150 if you do not specify any values and use relative sizing (while using bootstrap...etc). Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

The context object allows you to manipulate the canvas; you can draw rectangles for example and a lot more.

If you want to get the width and height, you can just use the standard HTML attributes `width` and `height`:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById( 'yourCanvasID' );
var ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

alert( canvas.width );
alert( canvas.height );
```

Comment: This answer is pretty much identical to @andrewmu's and won't work if you size the canvas via CSS. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032179/how-do-i-get-the-width-and-height-of-a-html5-canvas/31195651#31195651) for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 10):

now starting 2015 all (major?) browsers seem to alow `c.width` and `c.height` to get the canvas **internal** size, but:

the question as the answers are missleading, because the a canvas has in principle 2 different/independent sizes.

The "html" lets say CSS width/height and its own (attribute-) width/height

look at this [short example of different sizing](http://jsfiddle.net/pbw9cqft/), where I put a 200/200 canvas into a 300/100 html-element

With most examples (all I saw) there is no css-size set, so theese get implizit the width and height of the (drawing-) canvas size. But that is not a must, and can produce funy results, if you take the wrong size - ie. css widht/height for inner positioning.

Answer (score 1):

None of those worked for me. Try this.

```
console.log($(canvasjQueryElement)[0].width)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a CodePen that uses canvas.height/width, CSS height/width, and context to correctly render any canvas at any size](https://codepen.io/DoomGoober/pen/vYOvPJg).

HTML:

```
<button onclick="render()">Render</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="100" width="100" style="object-fit:contain;"></canvas>
```

CSS:

```
canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const originalHeight = myCanvas.height;
const originalWidth = myCanvas.width;
render();
function render() {
  let dimensions = getObjectFitSize(
    true,
    myCanvas.clientWidth,
    myCanvas.clientHeight,
    myCanvas.width,
    myCanvas.height
  );
  myCanvas.width = dimensions.width;
  myCanvas.height = dimensions.height;

  let ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
  let ratio = Math.min(
    myCanvas.clientWidth / originalWidth,
    myCanvas.clientHeight / originalHeight
  );
  ctx.scale(ratio, ratio); //adjust this!
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// adapted from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/intrinsic-scale
function getObjectFitSize(
  contains /* true = contain, false = cover */,
  containerWidth,
  containerHeight,
  width,
  height
) {
  var doRatio = width / height;
  var cRatio = containerWidth / containerHeight;
  var targetWidth = 0;
  var targetHeight = 0;
  var test = contains ? doRatio > cRatio : doRatio < cRatio;

  if (test) {
    targetWidth = containerWidth;
    targetHeight = targetWidth / doRatio;
  } else {
    targetHeight = containerHeight;
    targetWidth = targetHeight * doRatio;
  }

  return {
    width: targetWidth,
    height: targetHeight,
    x: (containerWidth - targetWidth) / 2,
    y: (containerHeight - targetHeight) / 2
  };
}
```

Basically, canvas.height/width sets the size of the bitmap you are rendering to. The CSS height/width then scales the bitmap to fit the layout space (often warping it as it scales it). The context can then modify it's scale to draw, using vector operations, at different sizes.