# Fabric.js: Canvas with 100% width possible?

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

When using 'canvas = new fabric.Canvas('foo')', Fabric converts the canvas element that has a css class with width=100% attached to it into something like that:

```
<div class="canvas-container" style="position: relative" width="293px">
  <canvas class="upper-canvas"></canvas>
  <canvas class="lower-canvas" id="c"></canvas>
</div>
```

The wrapping div as well as both canvas elements are getting style tags and fixed width/height. In terms of initialization, I´ve only found canvas.setWdith which only takes numeric values though (no percent values).

Is there a way to initialize Fabric to respect/use the given 100% width?

Update:
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/kb2Hp/

Comment: There seems no way to set the width to 100%, when trying to force it via CSS , Fabric stops working as expected.

Comment: solution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8486324/104380

Answer (score 26):

resize fabric's canvas by using its object and window innerWidth and innerHeight

```
(function(){
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('app');

  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

  function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
    canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    canvas.renderAll();
  }

  // resize on init
  resizeCanvas();
})();
```

Comment: Just in case if someone want to give specific div dimensions
canvas.setHeight($('.yourDiv').height()); 
canvas.setWidth($('.yourDiv').width());

Comment: If the page needs some time to setup its layout, it makes sense to postpone the call to `resizeCanvas()`. For me, a `window.setTimeout(resizeCanvas, 2000)` worked much more reliably.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure if you can explicitly tell Fabric to use 100% width, but perhaps get the width of  `canvas-container` through `$('.canvas-container').width()` or `document.getElementById('canvas-container').clientWidth`, and then using `canvas.setWidth` on that value? E.g.:

```
canvas.setWidth($('.canvas-container').width());
```

Protip: also remember to set this on window resize to prevent any overflow of content.

Comment: small change, but 'canvas-container' is injected as a class, not an id. So it should be '.canvas-container' not '#canvas-container'

Comment: Just to add some detail to Nick Mitchell's comment, Fabric wraps your host canvas in a div with the `canvas-container` class.

Answer (score 2):

Because the nature of [canvas element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element), [width](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#attr-canvas-width) and [height](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#attr-canvas-height) need be used in pixel. So, Fabric will not use a percent value to canvas.

```
attribute unsigned long width;
```

```
attribute unsigned long height;
```