# Draw a responsive grid of images using html5 Canvas2D

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm trying to plan a way to draw a 3 by 3 grid of images using Canvas2D so that the canvas takes up the full width and height of the browser window (and so each image is 1/3 the width and height).

This step is quite simple, but how would I achive this so that all the images resize correctly when the browsers window is resized?

Answer (score 0):

The first part of this question should be answered within [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288253/html5-canvas-100-width-height-of-viewport).

Then there are ways to get the actual width and height of the browser window. The relevant properties are [window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.innerWidth) and [window.innerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.innerHeight). When the resize event is triggered you'll want to run a function that finds the values of these properties and divide them by 3 to get your grid dimensions. Note that resizing the canvas will clear all bitmap data stored on it.