# Dynamically resize canvas within div element

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am working on a website and I want to take what I put in between the title tags and make it an element on the page itself.  I am also wanting to do some manipulating of the text like adding borders.  I am trying to do this with the canvas element, which I have been able to do successfully, but I cannot figure out how to make it scale.

I have found several answers to how to scale if it is taking up the whole screen, but not within div elements.  I have just started learning HTML5 and have never done anything like this before any help is appreciated.

javascript code below:

```
function makeCanvas(){
//1- Get Object
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('titlearea');
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
var title =  document.getElementById('pagetitle').text;

//2- Set parameters
ctx1.font = '32pt Arial';
ctx1.fillStyle = 'DeepSkyBlue';
ctx1.strokeStyle = 'Black';

//3- Action
ctx1.fillText(title,200,50);
ctx1.strokeText(title,200,50);
  }
```

HTML snippet below:

```
<div id="title">
    <canvas id="titlearea" width="2000" height="75"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS snippet below:

```
#title{
        background-color: #E6E6FA;
        color: #196405;
        font-size: large;
        border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
        padding: 1px;
        text-align: center;
        margin:0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 75px;
      }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set an explicit height and width on your `canvas` tag. In my experience, using CSS to set width/height of a canvas tag results in distortion of the canvas.

Take a look at this question for an example of how to resize a canvas dynamically via a resize handler in JavaScript: [HTML5 Canvas 100% Width Height of Viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288253/html5-canvas-100-width-height-of-viewport)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome this worked.  Now to figure out how to dynamically set the X and Y coordinates based on the canvas size.