# Centering fullscreen in javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen, center

I'm trying to make the fullscreen option work in html/javascript.

I have placed my canvas and buttons in a div, fullscreen works, But now I want to center my game in the middle of the screen, and I want my canvas height to be equal to the monitor height of the display. And I want my width to be equal to my height. So my canvas has the shape of a square.

I think I need css for this, but I never used it so I don't know where to start.

My html code looks now like this:

```
<div id="theGame">
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style=" position:absolute; top:40px; left:0px; border:6px  ridge #FFAB00;"></canvas>
<button buttonSpecs... </button>
<button buttonSpecs... </button>

</div>
```

Currently when I'm in fullscreen it looks like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ee4bv0cn2tm2nns/fullscreen.jpg

But thats not how I want it, I want it like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cu54fqz0gzap1ul/howIwant.jpg

Comment: So you are starting with canvas before knowing css fundamentals?

Comment: I was writing a little javascript game, not a website... We learn only javascript at school. But I want to use a bit of css/html in my game.

Answer (score 0):

See the following question: [HTML5 Canvas 100% Width Height of Viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288253/html5-canvas-100-width-height-of-viewport)

```
(function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

function resizeCanvas() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        /**
         * Your drawings need to be inside this function otherwise they will be reset when 
         * you resize the browser window and the canvas goes will be cleared.
         */
        drawStuff(); 
}
resizeCanvas();

function drawStuff() {
        // do your drawing stuff here
}
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I can now stretch the canvas, using

CSS:

```
#canvas {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0px; 
  top: 0px; 
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: user2815780, if you have more detail to add to your question, please edit your original text. You might also want to ask a whole new question.