# Combine javascript code to have <canvas> resize to browser size

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm venturing into javascript that i'm not really familiar with, and I am using code i found for drawing lines on both pc and smartphones, and it works nicely! (Found [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355230/HTML-5-Canvas-A-Simple-Paint-Program-Touch-and-Mou))

However whenever i tried placing the canvas somewhere on the page (mainly by doing `left:7em`) it also distorted the drawing by 7em inside the canvas, because of the fallback way of getting coordinates in the code.

I gave up the idea of placing the canvas and thought i was "just" going to have it cover the entire page, which was easier said then done. I found code for it here on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288253/html5-canvas-100-width-height-of-viewport)) but now i'm unsure how to combine these two scripts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Desktops and Tablets</title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
         initialize();
      });


      // works out the X, Y position of the click inside the canvas from the X, Y position on the page
      function getPosition(mouseEvent, sigCanvas) {
         var x, y;
         if (mouseEvent.pageX != undefined && mouseEvent.pageY != undefined) {
            x = mouseEvent.pageX;
            y = mouseEvent.pageY;
         } else {
            x = mouseEvent.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            y = mouseEvent.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
         }

         return { X: x - sigCanvas.offsetLeft, Y: y - sigCanvas.offsetTop };
      }

      function initialize() {
         // get references to the canvas element as well as the 2D drawing context
         var sigCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasSignature");
         var context = sigCanvas.getContext("2d");
         context.strokeStyle = 'Black';

         // This will be defined on a TOUCH device such as iPad or Android, etc.
         var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;

         if (is_touch_device) {
            // create a drawer which tracks touch movements
            var drawer = {
               isDrawing: false,
               touchstart: function (coors) {
                  context.beginPath();
                  context.moveTo(coors.x, coors.y);
                  this.isDrawing = true;
               },
               touchmove: function (coors) {
                  if (this.isDrawing) {
                     context.lineTo(coors.x, coors.y);
                     context.stroke();
                  }
               },
               touchend: function (coors) {
                  if (this.isDrawing) {
                     this.touchmove(coors);
                     this.isDrawing = false;
                  }
               }
            };

            // create a function to pass touch events and coordinates to drawer
            function draw(event) {

               // get the touch coordinates.  Using the first touch in case of multi-touch
               var coors = {
                  x: event.targetTouches[0].pageX,
                  y: event.targetTouches[0].pageY
               };

               // Now we need to get the offset of the canvas location
               var obj = sigCanvas;

               if (obj.offsetParent) {
                  // Every time we find a new object, we add its offsetLeft and offsetTop to curleft and curtop.
                  do {
                     coors.x -= obj.offsetLeft;
                     coors.y -= obj.offsetTop;
                  }
                  // The while loop can be "while (obj = obj.offsetParent)" only, which does return null
                  // when null is passed back, but that creates a warning in some editors (i.e. VS2010).
                  while ((obj = obj.offsetParent) != null);
               }

               // pass the coordinates to the appropriate handler
               drawer[event.type](coors);
            }


            // attach the touchstart, touchmove, touchend event listeners.
            sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchstart', draw, false);
            sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchmove', draw, false);
            sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchend', draw, false);

            // prevent elastic scrolling
            sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
               event.preventDefault();
            }, false); 
         }
         else {

            // start drawing when the mousedown event fires, and attach handlers to
            // draw a line to wherever the mouse moves to
            $("#canvasSignature").mousedown(function (mouseEvent) {
               var position = getPosition(mouseEvent, sigCanvas);

               context.moveTo(position.X, position.Y);
               context.beginPath();

               // attach event handlers
               $(this).mousemove(function (mouseEvent) {
                  drawLine(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context);
               }).mouseup(function (mouseEvent) {
                  finishDrawing(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context);
               }).mouseout(function (mouseEvent) {
                  finishDrawing(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context);
               });
            });

         }
      }

      // draws a line to the x and y coordinates of the mouse event inside
      // the specified element using the specified context
      function drawLine(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context) {

         var position = getPosition(mouseEvent, sigCanvas);

         context.lineTo(position.X, position.Y);
         context.stroke();
      }

      // draws a line from the last coordiantes in the path to the finishing
      // coordinates and unbind any event handlers which need to be preceded
      // by the mouse down event
      function finishDrawing(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context) {
         // draw the line to the finishing coordinates
         drawLine(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context);

         context.closePath();

         // unbind any events which could draw
         $(sigCanvas).unbind("mousemove")
                     .unbind("mouseup")
                     .unbind("mouseout");
      }
   </script>

</head>

<body>
   <h1>Canvas test</h1>

   <div id="canvasDiv">
      <!-- It's bad practice (to me) to put your CSS here.  I'd recommend the use of a CSS file! -->
      <canvas id="canvasSignature" width="500px" height="500px" style="border:2px solid #000000;"></canvas>
   </div>
</body>
```

```
(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

    function resizeCanvas() {
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

            /**
             * Your drawings need to be inside this function otherwise they will be reset when 
             * you resize the browser window and the canvas goes will be cleared.
             */
            drawStuff(); 
    }
    resizeCanvas();

    function drawStuff() {
            // do your drawing stuff here
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to control the height and width of your canvas instead of taking the whole screen you can do so by injecting the canvas as a child element to a div you have on your page.

```
<div id="yourCanvasBlock" style="width: 800px; height:500px">

</div>
```

then in your JavaScript you can add

```
<script>
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
div = document.getElementById("yourCanvasBlock");
div.appendChild(canvas)
</script>
```

Your canvas size can be adjusted in JavaScript as well.  similar to

```
 canvas.width  = 1224;
 canvas.height = 768;
```

Comment: Thank you, that made covering it to the whole page quite easy. So i went to try and make the width a bit shorter and then hang it on the right side, but this still causes the canvas to paint to the right of the cursor by the amount i subtract, unfortunately.