# sketch.js only works after refresh on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

i'm very confused about the error i got. It's hard to describe and give information about but i try:

i put the [sketch.js Paintingtool](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/) on my site. On iPhone it doesn't work so i searched a solution. [Here](https://github.com/intridea/sketch.js/issues/1) i finally found it und after i added it to the code i refreshed my page and all works fine.

Then i added [this code in my function what you see below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8486324/3623608)

Now i tried on iPhone again and it doesn't worked.
When i refresh the page it works without trouble.

With my laptop on the newest chrome browser everything works without refresh.

Can't i combine jQuery in Javascript code?

Here the code i use:

```
<div id="test">
<canvas id="tools_sketch"></canvas>
    <script>
        (function() {

            var canvas = document.getElementById('tools_sketch'),
                        context = canvas.getContext('2d');  

            // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
            window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

            function resizeCanvas() {
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
                canvas.width = infobox.offsetWidth;

                $(function() {      
                            $('#tools_sketch').sketch();
                });
            }
            resizeCanvas(); 
        })();
        </script>
</div>

<div class="tools center">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#tools_sketch" data-tool="marker">Pen</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#tools_sketch" data-tool="eraser">Rubber</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#tools_sketch" data-download="png">Send</a>
</div>
```

Thanks for reading

**EDIT:**
When i add the code from the official sketch.js to a new file on the server and reset the other file with that it works on iPhone. When i then change one line its broken. When i reset this line again its still broken. wtf!

**EDIT2:**
On Firefox 3.0 from 2008 it works, on Safari 3.1 from 2008 too -> not a old browser problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time (nearly a month) my problem is solved.

The reason for this problem was that i used [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks).

The simple and very easy solution was to change the turbolinks gems to [jQuery turbolinks](https://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-turbolinks).

Now it works without trouble.