# Get the browser viewport width and height no matter the size of the contents and without sizing to 100%?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to get the width and height of the page viewport NOT the contents of a page without setting the body width and height to 100%?

The answers I've found require the html and body elements to be set to 100% width and 100% height.

I already have content on the page that sometimes extends beyond the viewport size. I can't switch the body to 100% and then check the values and then revert back.

In my opinion there should be a property that is simply:

```
document.body.viewportWidth;
document.body.viewportHeight;
```

That update on window resize and exclude the chrome.

There are related questions here:

[HTML5 Canvas 100% Width Height of Viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288253/html5-canvas-100-width-height-of-viewport)

**Update:**
I've been using this:

```
var availableWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var availableHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
```

It might be that the viewport values are correct but the element itself is growing or shrinking.

I can't find the document.documentElement.clientWidth or document.documentElement.clientHeight in the [documentElement docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) though.

**Update 2:**
It looks like it might be an error on my part. I noticed in the logs that occasionally the element has no computed width or height possibly because it hasn't been added to the page yet.

```
var elementWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element, "style").width);
var elementHeight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element, "style").height);
```

I think the code I'm already using above is correct.

**Update 3:**
I found this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts) on getting the viewport size.

Comment: clientWidth and clientHeight are defined in the [CSSOM View spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-element-clientwidth) On the documentElement is gives the viewport dimensions minus any scrollbars.

Comment: window.innerWidth and innerHeight are also defined there. They give the viewport dimensions including any scrollbars.

Answer (score 4):

I may not understand your question correctly, but if you're looking for the height and width of the browser window, you could use `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth`.

Here is some more information on the window [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) and [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) that could be useful.

Comment: Yeah I've been using something like that. I've updated the post. I think my issue it may be unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth
document.documentElement.clientHeight
```

Answer (score 1):

Does [window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) and [window.innerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) work for you?