# Fit canvas size to background image size, keeping its aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am currently developing an app allowing users to draw shapes top of an image.

I am using canvas with `background-image` set to `url("uploaded image_url")`.

**I am having trouble getting canvas size fitted to background image size and to the viewport size at once.**

Consider the following snipper - a lot of the lower image is cropped:

```css
.drawer-area {
  width: 90%;
  background-image: url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/430/200/300.jpg?hmac=souGSmvwQ6KlJgthGYBGSWB22Y7MpK5xlgLYwvtbXzg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="drawer-area"></canvas>
```

Note, I don't know the size of the image beforehand. I am using `background-size: cover` and `width: 90%`, but it doesn't do the trick. Any advice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8486324/11729652 I guess this is what you're looking for)

Comment: Is it just a height issue?

Comment: so you want the canvas to set it's width and height automatically according to the background-size?

Comment: @KALITA precisely :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like this on your style sheet?
`background: url("uploaded image_url") center center/ cover no-repeat;`
This should make the image fit into the container you've assigned it to, hope it helps!