# Style.length and Style.width are not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    console.log(document.getElementById("myCanvas").style.length);
```

I have this code in my program. It returns 0, despite the length of the canvas being 660. Does anyone know why?

Comment: can you add the html for `myCanvas`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the width and height of a HTML5 canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032179/how-do-i-get-the-width-and-height-of-a-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the width and height through this.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
```

Answer (score 2):

In CSS there is no length attribute, there is just height or width. You can use this:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("myCanvas").style.height);
console.log(document.getElementById("myCanvas").style.width);
```